# Conversion of string to JSON object in JavaScript with eval()

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am converting the following JSON variable to string. When back to JSON, I'm getting an error (in ReactJS, although it shouldn't be important).

```
var questionGlobal = {
  "questionCons": [{
    "string": "In",
    "alignment": 2
  }, {
    "string": "New York State",
    "alignment": 1
  }, {
    "string": "the",
    "alignment": -1
  }, {
    "string": "shortest",
    "alignment": -1
  }, {
    "string": "period",
    "alignment": 0
  }, {
    "string": "of",
    "alignment": 2
  }, {
    "string": "daylight",
    "alignment": 0
  }, {
    "string": "occurs",
    "alignment": 2
  }, {
    "string": "during",
    "alignment": 1
  }, {
    "string": "which",
    "alignment": 0
  }, {
    "string": "month",
    "alignment": 0
  }],
  "options": [{
    "string": "January",
    "alignment": 1
  }, {
    "string": "December",
    "alignment": 2
  }, {
    "string": "June",
    "alignment": 1
  }, {
    "string": "July",
    "alignment": 1
  }]
};
```

Here is the command:

```
window.console.log( eval(JSON.stringify(questionGlobal)));
```

The output that I get in console is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Any idea where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: JSON on its own is not necessarily valid JS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use `JSON.parse`.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(questionGlobal)));
```

When using `eval()` it is required that you pass a valid JS statement. One you could actually write without the `eval` and without getting any errors.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zq5z9f9y/)